# What's the 1 required pos. argument, please?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am receiving an error in regards to a 'missing positional argument:self'. Any thoughts please?

I am still learning how to read error. Also,  why is 'screen1' under register_user function responding with unresolved reference when the cursor is hovering over it?

---

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Samuel Mireku\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:/Users/Samuel Mireku/PycharmProjects/Works/Form.py", line 5, in register_user
        username_info = username.get()
    TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

---

```
from tkinter import *

def register_user():

    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    f = open(username_info+".txt", 'w')
    f.write(username_info)
    f.write(password_info)
    f.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete (0, END)

    Label(screen1, text = 'Registration is a success').pack()

def register():
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title('Register')
    screen1.geometry('300x250')

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username = StringVar
    password = StringVar

    Label(screen1, text='Enter details below').pack()
    Label(screen1, text='').pack()
    Label(screen1, text='username *').pack()
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
    username_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text='password *').pack()
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable=password)
    password_entry.pack()
    Button(screen1, text = 'Register', width = 10, height = 1, command = register_user).pack()


def login():
    print('Login session started')


def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry ('300x250')
    screen.title('Notes1.0')
    Label(text = 'Notes', bg = 'grey', font = ('Arial',13)).pack()
    Label(text = '').pack()
    Button(text ='Login', height = '2', width = '30', command = login).pack()
    Label(text = '').pack()
    Button(text ='Register', height = '2', width = '30', command = register).pack()

    screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

Comment: Did you mean `username = StringVar()`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that:

```
username = StringVar
password = StringVar
```

need to be:

```
username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
```

Without the parentheses, they are the class itself, not instances of the class.  So when invoking `get`, it's just a function, not a method.  So the `self` parameter is not set, which is what caused the error message.